# Xamarin error: The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\\mainDexClasses.bat" is invalid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am getting the following error when I tried to run my App in Visual Studio 2013 with xamarin plugin. "The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\mainDexClasses.bat" is invalid."

Anyone Knows about this error ?? Please help.